# How can I change a variable from another script with onclick() in an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a script called main.js that is attached to index.html. I have an `onclick()` function set up within index.html that needs to change the value of a variable. This question would be easy if the script was written with script tags, however, despite trying to figure it out, I'm not sure how to do it when the script is referenced via a script tag. The code isn't really relevant to the question, but here's the line anyway.

```
<li><a href="main.html" onclick='card=thing;'>thing</a></li>
```

card is a variable in main.js which needs to be changed. In main.js, before the `onclick()` event, card is set to NULL. Thanks so much.

Comment: write a function in main.html with script tag or in main.js and call it onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write function in script tags or in main.js, and call it onclick

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='changeCard("thing")'>thing</a></li>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeCard(val) {
        card = val;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have to say, after your seeing your comment suggestions, I did exactly this, without seeing this response, down to the function name and everything, not gonna lie, I'm a bit spooked. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @Zanolon I also expected that.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function in the home.js and inside the function you can access and change the href variable.

html should be like this

```
<li><a  id="variable" href="main.html" onclick='card=thing;'>thing</a></li>
```

in thee function add this line

```
document.getElementById("variable").href="your reference";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is fine in terms of syntax, because if the main.js file is linked to the same html where this line is, then `card` is a global variable that you could override without any problem.

Though the problem in this case might be other, because you are changing that variable when user clicks an anchor tag which is pointing to a main.html file in its href attribute.

So what will actually happen is that two event handlers will be executed, the first one will be your code changing the value of that variable and the second will actually redirect your window to another html file, changing the actual context of your current window and making its global variables no longer useful, and that makes no sense.

If you want to do something in js before navigating somewhere else then you would need to attach an event handler to the anchor element and call `event.preventDefault()` method to prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag when it is clicked, in other words, prevent navigation. That would look something like this:

```
// Js code:
var anchor = document.querySelector('a')
anchor.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // Do the stuff you want to do on click here, before navigating, etc
    card = thing

    // ... explicitly navigate
})
```